# Read installed Ubuntu version in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, ubuntu

how can I get the installed Ubuntu version in a PowerShell script like this command "**lsb_release -d**" do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try if this works for you:

```
$output = lsb_release -d
$version = $output -replace 'Description:',''
$version = $version.Trim()
Write-Output "The installed version of Ubuntu is: $version"
```